# When happened to the passed object?

Tags: javascript, disqus

`DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount` is called with a single argument
`{"text":{"and":"and","comments":{"zero":"0 Comments","multiple":"{num} Comments","one":"1 Comment"}},"counts":[]}`:

[image]

But when inside `DISQUSWIDGETS.displayCount` the passed argument has value of `Object {zero: "0 Comments", multiple: "{num} Comments", one: "1 Comment"}`:

[image]

Using Google Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit)

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Because of this argument mangling comment count is not updated on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is below

```
a = a.text.comments;
```

Comment: Yes, looks like your are right, because `i` also already has a value. I didn't expect the line already to be executed. This means that the problem is with disqus data received from the server. There is one comment, but `"counts":[]`. I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.